# How to delay a counter until animation is finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a fancy animation for a shoppingcart which moves a cart icon from the product to the top corner and it will do a +1 on the counter with angularJS. However at the time the animated cart reaches the top the counter is already +1. It would be awesome if I was able to delay the angularJS counter so that it will be added when the animation is completed.

**HTML**

```
<li>({{orderTotal()}}) <i id="cart" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Order </a></li>
```

**JS**

```
function flyToElement(flyer, flyingTo) {
  if (jQuery(window).width() > 767) {

    var $func = $(this);
    var divider = 1;
    var flyerClone = $(flyer).clone();
    $(flyerClone).css({position: 'absolute', top: $(flyer).offset().top + "px", left: $(flyer).offset().left + "px", opacity: 1, 'z-index': 1000});
    $('body').append($(flyerClone));

    var gotoX = $(flyingTo).offset().left + ($(flyingTo).width() /2) - ($(flyer).width()/divider)/2-5;
    var gotoY = $(flyingTo).offset().top + ($(flyingTo).height() /2) - ($(flyer).height()/divider)/2-5;

    $(flyerClone).animate({
        opacity: 1.0,
        left: gotoX,
        top: gotoY

    }, 500,
    function () {
      $(flyingTo).fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $(flyingTo).fadeIn('fast', function () {
          $(flyerClone).fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(flyerClone).fadeIn('fast', function () {
              $(flyerClone).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                $(flyerClone).remove();
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  };
}
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.orderTotal = function(index) {
  var orderTotal = 0;
  angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(items) {
    orderTotal += items.quantity;
  })
  return orderTotal;
};
```

I'm looking for some advise on how to do this. Thanks

**SOLUTION**

Using $timeout()

```
var kvv = angular.module('kvv', ['ngStorage']);
kvv.controller('CartController', function($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {


    $scope.addToCart = function(index, title, desc, price, timeout) {
        var found = false;
        angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(items) {
            if (items.id  === index) {
              $timeout(function() {(items.quantity++)}, 500);
              found = true;
            }
        });
        if (!found) {
           $timeout(function() {$localStorage.items
           .push(angular.extend({
             id: index,
             title: title,
             quantity: 1,
             price: price}, index))},500);
        }
      };
});
```

Comment: You can try broadcasting an "event" when cart reaches the destination and using `$on(event) ` in your angular script for your `orderTotal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) is what you need.

```
var kvv = angular.module('kvv', ['ngStorage'])
  .controller('CartController', function($scope, $timeout, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {
    $scope.checked = false;
    $scope.addToCart = function(index, title, desc, price) {
      $scope.checked = true;
      var found = false;
      angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(items) {
        if (items.id  === index) {
          $timeout(function() {
            (items.quantity++);
            $scope.checked = false;
          }, 500);
          found = true;
        }
      });
      if (!found) {
       $timeout(function() {
         $localStorage.items.push(angular.extend({
           id: index,
           title: title,
           quantity: 1,
           price: price}, index))
       },500);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: I've tried this but cant seem to get it working. With the examples i've found they start a loop and crash my browser. I've tried to set an timeout just between the return and the end of the counter in de angurlarjs part.

Comment: It returns an error on the console; timeout is not a function. Also this probably will add an delay while counting. It should create a timeout when counting is completed so that the cart animation can finish before the total will get updated.

By the way; I also added $timeout to the ngcontroller

Comment: Updated once more. Can you create a plnkr please? I'm not sure to have understood what your are searching for.

Comment: Its a bit complex to extract all the required code but basically i'm having an animation that moves a cart icon from the product to the top right corner on top of a shoppingcart icon next to a angularjs variable called {{orderTotal()}}. Because it takes some time to let the icon move over the screen the eyes of the potential customer are not focussed on the counter. Only when the animated icon arrives at the top right corner they'll see the counter because its next to the shoppingcart icon.

Comment: So the idea is to delay the counter return so that the customer is seeing the counter do a +1 instead of a +1 while he is still focussed with his eyes on the animation. I thought this could be accomplished by delaying the return of {{orderTotal}} so that the animation can finish. Not the best perhaps but it does the job.

Comment: Oh ok, then you need to use `$timing` not in your `{{orderTotal}}`, but in what triggers it: are you using an `ng-click="function()` somewhere?

Comment: Yes I am

`ng-click="addToCart(' 
                                . $row["pId"] . ',\''
                                . $row["pTitle"] . '\',\''
                                . $row["pDesc"] . '\',\''
                                . $row["pPrice"] . '\');" class="shortcode_button btn btn-success add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> Add</a>';`
the addToCart function adds the product to the array.

Comment: Whoa that's fairly hard to read. I highly suggest you to move all of that into a function and call it with `ng-click="addItem()`, and then add a delay.
But if you don't want, just delay your `addToCart`.

Comment: I've added the addToCart function to the original question. Could you show my how I should implement the timeout?

Comment: Thanks but still $timeout not a function error. Error placed in original question

Comment: Sorry, still same. I've updated the AngularJS code together with the controller info as well. With your last version the counter itself was not working either. In previous versions it was.

Comment: Add `$timeout` in the controller's dependencies.

Comment: Have you got any news?

Comment: Going to try it now. Had to get the cat from the petclinic.

Comment: Sadly still the same.

Comment: Please be sure to have done everything right. I'm getting no errors in localhost and on plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/tQ3ktPxKVnop9TUhlHk9?p=preview (on plnkr I removed storage dependencies)

Comment: Aaaah, in the addToChart function you used $timeout instead of timeout. Changed it and now it works accordingly.

Comment: yay indeed. Still I find it strange that in the plnkr you used $timeout and that works. But we me it doesnt. :-s

Comment: Not sure about what you mean, do you feel strange to use `$timeout` rather than `timeout`? If is that, it's because it belongs to angular!

Comment: Oh, seen your suggested edit! Well, I really don't know why lol

Comment: Well it works for me when I use timeout instead of $timeout. When I use $timeout in the addToCart function it gives the "timeout not a function error". If $timeout is not working on my setup I would expect the same error on plnkr.

Comment: I really don't know what to say, I myself am using `$timeout` in my projects and works ahah

Comment: Something to investigate when I don't have a deadline :-) Thanks again Emanuele!

Comment: One additional questions because the timeout is causing a problem.

When I add a new item while the array ($localStorage.items) is empty. And during the first timeout i'll add several others they are not checked for duplicates because the array is not yet filled but another product is added already. Resulting in an array with multiple items of the same without the counter adding just 1 item.

Comment: example: 
1) I hit the Add to ShoppingCart Icon
2) Timeout starts
3) During this timeout I push Add to ShoppingCart Icon of the same item again
4) Now the function checks to see if this item is already added but its not because its still in the timeout.

Comment: Yeah that obviously solves the problem but also brings me back to the initial request :) Is there a way to see if there is already another timeout going on and then put the request in some kind of queue?

Comment: You should disable the button for 500ms, right now I can't work on it but I'll do asap (if you won't solve it before me :P)

Comment: I can't myself so to be continued :)

Comment: Check [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MOMiHWV5Z2jkMJb1S0sr?p=preview) in your project please, check if it works, if it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` and if `checked` is set on `false` after 500ms that you clicked on the button. If so, play around as we did to let `$timeout` works.

Comment: works, the only thing i've added was when !found :-)

Comment: So does it work as expected? Does it become clickable again after 500ms?

Answer (score 1):

In angular your data is bound at the moment the event is executed. And anything bound to that data will show the current state of the data. You should either move your jQuery or jqlite into some form of service in Angular and use a $apply at the end of our function nesting or chaining or wrap it in the $watch as previously mentioned. Good info on $apply and $watch [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html). Or Just do the entire thing in jQuery using the same strategies. The issue comes down to using two DOM tools separately. You can totally use them together.

Answer (score 0):

You should use css for the animation. Using JQuery in AngularJS should be minimized as much as possible, or you're complicating your life needlessly. Future maintenance will be a nightmare.

You can accomplish this using an animation directive that adds and removes a certain class based on the animation state, and combine that with a $watch to determine when the final state of the animation is executed (ie. element is removed, or final class [ie. animation-end] is attached).